# How to wrap jqueryUI tooltip with custom div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

So by default, a tooltip is created with the parent div containing `.ui-tooltip`. Is there any way I can do something like this to wrap `.ui-tooltip` in a custom div, **without using another library**?

```
$(tooltipTrigger).tooltip({
  tooltipClass: "custom-tooltip-styling", // this works
  tooltipWrapper: "<div class='custom-tooltip-wrapper'></div>" // this is what I want to work
});
```

I basically want the output to look like this:

```
<div class="custom-tooltip-wrapper">
  <div class="ui-tooltip custom-tooltip-styling"></div>
</div>
```

I tried using `.wrap()` within `.tooltip()`, but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`open`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-open) - event to wrap your div around the created tooltip:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    tooltipClass: "custom-tooltip-styling",
    open: function(event, ui) {
      $(ui.tooltip).wrap("<div class='custom-tooltip-wrapper'></div>");
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $('.custom-tooltip-wrapper').remove();
    }
});
```

However, you need to style your wrapper accordingly, it otherwise will just appear at the end of the page.
I use the [`close`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-close) - event here to get rid of the wrapper afterwards.

---

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0uu5a9Ly/)**